# Copy image to clipboard with xclip doesn't work properly

Tags: clipboard, images

So, I tried the following

```
xclip -se c -t image/png -i imagefile.jpg
```

This does indeed copy the image into clipboard, and I can paste it into `gimp`, or paste it into a new image file as in the following.

```
xclip -se c -t image/png -o > newimage.jpg
```

But, when I try to paste image copied in this way, I can't paste it into facebook messenger or posts. Why is that? And how do I get around this?

**N.B** I use xfce4-screenshooter, and it has an option to save screenshot to clipboard. If I use that I can paste that image data into facebook messenger and posts. So, it must be a problem with either my process or with `xclip` itself. What does xfce4-screenshooter uses?

Comment: this might help https://superuser.com/a/1098582

Comment: Yeah, my xclip version is 0.12. I'll get back to you after updating it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [superuser.com/a/1098582](https://superuser.com/a/1098582). I'm copying it here because the OP for that answer isn't related to `xclip` specifically. Keeping the answer here will be beneficial to people who come to this question in the future.

---

Install `xclip` (be sure the version is at least 0.12+svn84, because 0.12 is not enough); then, use the following method to copy image to system clipboard:

```
cat /path/to/image | xclip -selection clipboard -target image/png -i
```

---

**Update**: the current version of `xclip` in apt repo for Ubuntu 20.04 is 0.13, which is new enough for this answer to work.

Answer (score 0):

This could also be a reason it doesn't work: https://github.com/astrand/xclip/issues/110

According to this issue, some programs are picky about the format of image they'll accept. Many clipboard providers convert the image on-the-fly to the format the program wants, but xclip doesn't do this. In particular, if you copy in a JPEG image, it will not work for some programs, such as Discord. They mention GIMP as an exception which accepts JPEG directly.

The issue provides a temporary workaround: convert the image to png first.

```
convert image.jpeg png:- | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png -i
```